# DropNet Authentication without prompts and File Sharing

Tags: dropnet

Couple of questions:

1. I implemented the authentication process with DropNet. My desktop application is designed for end-users. Every time the application is launch the little browser window pops up asking the user to confirm access...
   Is there any way that end-user with SOME SORT of saved credentials (or user Code +user Secret, or API code + API secret) will be able to invoke the application and not be prompted by browser form (that currently requires login - if access token expired - or confirmation)?
2. The goal of my application is file sharing - that is, one end user may send URL (to the file that he uploaded to DropBox) to another user and the latter should be able to download the file by clicking on the link (without any prompts, exactly like in manual process of sharing link to the file in DropBox). Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve that? THat is how do I get that URL? Redandent to say that I am looking for a programmatic way to obtain a URL that will achieve the above described)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, please read the API documentation for the Dropbox API. https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs It will answer some of your questions for you.

1. Yes it is possible to save the authentication token to save the user logging in every time. At the end of the authentication process after calling `GetAccessToken()` the DropNetClient instance will have a property called `UserLogin` this contains a User token and secret. Store these, then next time you create an instance of the DropNetClient user the constructor that takes these as parameters.
2. The API has the ability to get a share link for a file. This is exposed by DropNet with the `GetShare` and `GetShareAsync` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, thanks for the tips, now work, The file is uploaded to a folder within the dropbox app, here's the code:

```
Dim client As DropNetClient
    Dim dropboxLoggedIn As Boolean = False
    Dim dropboxAsecret
    Dim dropboxAtoken
    Dim token As UserLogin
    Dim url As String = ""

    Private Sub test_form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


        client = New DropNetClient("xxxxxx", "xxxxxxx")
        client.UseSandbox = True

        Dim login = client.UserLogin

        token = client.GetToken()
        url = client.BuildAuthorizeUrl()

        Process.Start(url)

    End Sub


    Private Sub ButtonX2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonX2.Click

        client.GetAccessToken()
        dropboxAsecret = client.UserLogin.Secret
        dropboxAtoken = client.UserLogin.Token


        Try
            Dim rawData As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("c:\flor_lotus.png")
            Dim result As MetaData = client.UploadFile("/geral", "flor_lotus.png", rawData)
        Catch ex As DropNet.Exceptions.DropboxException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```